# pyqtgraph real time plot freezes after resizing

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I'm plotting real time data received over UDP in pyqtgraph. Everything works great with 2048 points per update, but with 4096 or 8k points the plot freezes as soon as I try to resize or zoom in.   If I toggle logY scale the updates resume.   I've verified that there are no gaps in the UDP stream.  also tried to use

```
# p.setDownsampling(auto=True)
# p.setClipToView(True)
```

options, but they did not help

I've read that pyqtgraph can handle a lot more data than this, so I'm a bit puzzled.  The problem can be seen here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iL-WHEbSx-w

Here is the code, I took it straight from the examples with only minor changes

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.ptime import time

from struct import pack, unpack

from socket import *

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

data = []

p = pg.plot(fillLevel=20)
p.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: PlotSpeedTest')
p.setRange(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 30720000, 10 )) 
p.setLabel('bottom', 'Frequency', units='Hz')
p.showGrid(True, True)
fScale = np.linspace(0, 30720000, 8192)

# p.setDownsampling(auto=True)
# p.setClipToView(True)

curve = p.plot()

# Receive UDP packets transmitted by a broadcasting service

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
try:
        sock.bind(('', 1234))
except:
        print "Error connecting to the UDP stream."
        quit


ptr = 0
lastTime = time()
fps = None
def update():
    global sock, fScale
    global curve, data, ptr, p, lastTime, fps
    stream = sock.recv(16384)
    if (len(stream) == 16384):
        data_float16 = np.fromstring(stream, dtype=np.float16)
        data = data_float16.astype(np.float32)
        print "got data", lastTime, "\n"
    # print data
    curve.setData(fScale,data,_callSync='off')
    # curve.setData(data,_callSync='off')
    now = time()
    dt = now - lastTime
    lastTime = now
    if fps is None:
        fps = 1.0/dt
    else:
        s = np.clip(dt*3., 0, 1)
        fps = fps * (1-s) + (1.0/dt) * s
    p.setTitle('%0.2f fps' % fps)
    app.processEvents()  ## force complete redraw for every plot
timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.start(0)


## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have any `Inf` in the data, then it confuses the bounding rectangle calculations that determine whether to redraw the plot. Try cleaning the data first:

```
data[np.isinf(data)] = np.nan
```

Comment: wow you are absolutely right. I printed data and saw a few Inf's.  I would have never thought of this. Thanks!